# Why did these lines of Assembly crash QtSpim?

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

This is a block of code I had to describe a subprogram. QtSpim crashed when I opened the file. I didn't get a chance to run it.

```
###########################################################
# Read Structure
# # #
# 1. Iterate through the array and read each element from user input
# 2. Each element should be a [double, integer] pair 
#       - Double: “price” 
#       - Integer: “count”
###########################################################
```

Here is the rest of my unfinished program if it helps. I only found out what was wrong after isolating sections with print statements and deleting chunks then re-running/crashing QtSpim.

```
###########################################################
# Program 5 - Data Structure
# # #
# 1. Dynamically Allocate and fill Array of Data Structures 
# 2. Print Out Array
# 4. Iterate Array and calculate sum and average
#       - Value of each element = (price x count)
#       - Array Average = (total value / total count)
# 6. Iterate again to find the min and max values
# 7. Print sum, average, min and max value.

# #  Main's Order  # #
# Allocate Structure #
# Read Structure     #
# Print Structure    #
# Sum Average        #
# Get Min/Max        #
# # # # # # # # # # # 
###########################################################
#       Register Usage
#   $t0 
#   $t1
#   $t2 
#   $t3 
#   $t4 
#   $t5
#   $t6
#   $t7
#   $t8
#   $t9 Temp
###########################################################
        .data
# "sv" - Static Variable

ArrayAddress_sv:    .word   0   
ArraySize_sv:       .word   0   

###########################################################
        .text
main:

    addi $sp, $sp, -4   # Allocate space for $ra
    sw $ra, 0($sp)      # Store $ra onto stack

    addi $sp, $sp, -8   # Allocate space for |2-Arg's OUT(Array Base Address/Array Length)|

    jal allocate_structure

    lw $t0, 0($sp)      # Loading Array Address($sp+0) to $t0
    lw $t1, 4($sp)      # Loading Array Size($sp+4) to $t1

    addi $sp, $sp, 8    # De-Allocating 2 Arguments

    lw $ra, 0($sp)              # load $ra from stack
    addi $sp, $sp, 4            # deallocate word for $ra

    la $t9, ArrayAddress_sv     # Loading Address of Static Variable
    sw $t0, 0($t9)              # Storing Array Address($t0) into Static Variable(ArrayAddress_sv)

    la $t9, ArraySize_sv        # Loading Address of Static Variable
    sw $t1, 0($t9)              # Storing Array Size($t1) into Static Variable(ArraySize_sv)

# # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# Allocate Structure Done #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # #

    la $t9, ArrayAddress_sv # Loading Address of Static Variable
    lw $t0, 0($t9)          # Storing Variable(Array Address) into $t0
                                # # # RESTORING VARIABLES # # #
    la $t9, ArraySize_sv    # Loading Address of Static Variable
    lw $t1, 0($t9)          # Storing Variable(Array Length) into $t1 

    addi $sp, $sp, -4   # Allocate space for $ra
    sw $ra, 0($sp)      # Store $ra onto stack

    addi $sp, $sp, -8   # Allocate space for |2-Arg's IN(Array Base Address/Array Length)|

    sw $t0, 0($sp)      # Storing Array Address into $sp+0
    sw $t1, 4($sp)      # Storing Array Length into $sp+4

    jal read_structure

    addi $sp, $sp, 8    # De-Allocate space for |2-Arg's IN(Array Base Address/Array Length)|

    lw $ra, 0($sp)              # load $ra from stack
    addi $sp, $sp, 4            # deallocate word for $ra

# # # # # # # # # # # # 
# Read Structure Done #
# # # # # # # # # # # #

    la $t9, ArrayAddress_sv # Loading Address of Static Variable
    lw $t0, 0($t9)          # Storing Variable(Array Address) into $t0
                                # # # RESTORING VARIABLES # # #
    la $t9, ArraySize_sv    # Loading Address of Static Variable
    lw $t1, 0($t9)          # Storing Variable(Array Length) into $t1 

    addi $sp, $sp, -4           # allocate one word for $ra
    sw $ra, 0($sp)              # store $ra on stack

    addi $sp, $sp, -8   # Allocate space for |2-Arg's IN(Array Base Address/Array Length)|

    sw $t0, 0($sp)      # Storing Array Address into $sp+0
    sw $t1, 4($sp)      # Storing Array Length into $sp+4

    jal print_structure

    addi $sp, $sp, 8    # De-Allocate space for |2-Arg's IN(Array Base Address/Array Length)|

    lw $ra, 0($sp)              # load $ra from stack
    addi $sp, $sp, 4            # deallocate word for $ra

# # # # # # # # # # # # 
# Print Structure Done #
# # # # # # # # # # # #


    addi $sp, $sp, 4    # De-Allocating $ra

    li $v0, 10      #End Program
    syscall
###########################################################
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
###########################################################
# Allocate Structure
# # #
# 1. Prompt user for an array size 
# 2. Dynamically allocate an array of data structures
# 3. Return array base address and array size to main
###########################################################
# Arguments In and Out of subprogram
#   $sp+0 Array Base Address(OUT)
#   $sp+4 Array Size(OUT)
###########################################################
# Register Usage
#   $t0 Array Size
#   $t1 12
###########################################################
        .data

InvalidSize_p:  .asciiz "\nThe size you entered was invalid."
ArraySize_p:    .asciiz "\nEnter size of the array: "
###########################################################
        .text
allocate_structure:

    li $v0, 4               # # #
    la $a0, ArraySize_p     # Print "Enter an array length: "
    syscall                 # # #

    li $v0, 5
    syscall

    blez $v0, invalid_size  # If entered length <= 0 display error

    move $t0, $v0

    li $t1, 12

    li $v0, 9
    mul $a0, $t0, $t1
    syscall

    sw $v0, 0($sp) # Saving $v0(Array Address) on stack
    sw $t0, 4($sp) # Saving $t0(Array Size) on stack

    jr $ra  #return to main

invalid_size:

    li $v0, 4               # # #
    la $a0, InvalidSize_p   # Print "\nThe size you entered was invalid."
    syscall                 # # #

    b allocate_structure
###########################################################
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
###########################################################
# Read Structure
# # #
# 1. Iterate through the array and read each element from user input
# 2. Each element should be a [double, integer] pair 
#       - Double: “price” 
#       - Integer: “count”
###########################################################
# Arguments In and Out of subprogram
#   $sp+0 Array Base Address(IN)
#   $sp+4 Array Size(IN)
###########################################################
# Register Usage
#   $t0 Array Address
#   $t1 Array Size
#   $t2 Counter
###########################################################
        .data
Price_p:    .asciiz "\n Enter Price(Double) for Item "
Count_p:    .asciiz "\n Enter Count(Integer) for Item "
Input_p:    .asciiz " : "
InvalidRead_p:  .asciiz "\n The number you entered is invalid"
###########################################################
        .text
read_structure:

    lw $t0, 0($sp)      # Loading Array Address($sp+0) to $t0
    lw $t1, 4($sp)      # Loading Array Size($sp+4) to $t1

    li $t2, 1

read_structure_loop:

    li $v0, 4           # # #
    la $a0, Price_p     # Print "\n Enter Price(Double) for Item "
    syscall             # # #

    li $v0, 1           # # #
    move $a0, $t2       # Print Counter Integer
    syscall             # # #

    li $v0, 4           # # #
    la $a0, Input_p     # Print " : "
    syscall             # # #


    li $v0, 7   # Read Double
    syscall

    #c.le.d $f0, $zero  # Double is <= Zero
    #bc1t invalid_read  # # #

    li $v0, 4           # # #
    la $a0, Price_p     # Print "\n Enter Count(Integer) for Item "
    syscall             # # #

    li $v0, 1           # # #
    move $a0, $t2       # Print Counter Integer
    syscall             # # #

    li $v0, 4           # # #
    la $a0, Input_p     # Print " : "
    syscall             # # #

    li $v0, 5           # Read Int
    syscall

    blez $v0, invalid_read  # Int is <= zero

    s.d $f0, 0($t0)     # Store Double into array

    sw $v0, 8($t0)      # Store Int into Array

    addi $t0, $t0, 12   # Move Pointer 
    addi $t2, $t2, 1    # Increment Counter

    blt $t2, $t1, read_structure_loop # If counter < array size, then loop again

    jr $ra  # Return to main

invalid_read:

    li $v0, 4               # # #
    la $a0, InvalidRead_p   # Print "\n The number you entered is invalid"
    syscall                 # # #

    b read_structure_loop
###########################################################
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
###########################################################
# Print Structure
# # #
# 1. Iterate the array and print the content of each element "[double, integer]
###########################################################
# Arguments In and Out of subprogram
#   $sp+0 Array Base Address(IN)
#   $sp+4 Array Size(IN)
###########################################################
# Register Usage
###########################################################
        .data
###########################################################
        .text
print_structure:

    jr $ra  #return to 
###########################################################
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
###########################################################
# Sum Average 
# # #
# 1. Iterate the array and calculate the sum and average
# 2. Value is (price x count)
# 3. Average is (total value / total count)
###########################################################
# Arguments In and Out of subprogram
#   $sp+0  Array Base Address(IN)
#   $sp+4  Array Size(IN)
#   $sp+8  Sum Calculated Sums in data structure array(OUT)
#   $sp+16 Average of calculated sums in data structure array(OUT)
###########################################################
# Register Usage
###########################################################
        .data
###########################################################
        .text
sum_average:

    jr $ra  #return to main
###########################################################
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
###########################################################
# Get Min/Max
# # #
# 1. Iterate the array and find minimum value and maximum value
#       - Total Value = (price x count)
###########################################################
# Arguments In and Out of subprogram
#   $sp+0  Array Base Address(IN)
#   $sp+4  Array Size(IN)
#   $sp+8  Min Value(OUT)
#   $sp+16 Max Value(OUT)
###########################################################
# Register Usage
###########################################################
        .data
###########################################################
        .text
get_min_max:

    jr $ra  #return to main
###########################################################
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
###########################################################
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I suspect it got confused by the `[]`. If QtSpim is open source and you care, attach a debugger to it.

Comment: Actually, I tried narrowing it down even more and it was the two lines under that. Maybe it had something to do with the colon and quotations being next to each other. Maybe it read the Doube and Int as variables, but it's still confusing because they came after the hash marks.

Comment: Wasn't it the UTF-8 quotes `“price”`? Aren't these SPIM-family tools mostly ASCII limited, not aware of unicode strings? Try to add into source those two lines back, and delete the colons first, if it works, and then try to delete the unicode quotes instead?

Comment: MARS under 64b linux has no problem to open the file, shows those lines as comments, and building the empty source will successfully produce no machine code, so it's SPIM-only problem. (unfortunately I don't have any SPIM to try it out myself, usually having MARS is enough to cover both types of questions, but in your case it's obviously useless "JFYI").

Comment: Unable to reproduce with QtSpim 9.1.12 on Windows 7.

Comment: @JustinFranecki: I'd suggest editing the question down to just the 2 line [mcve] you found.  It doesn't have to be a complete program, just a fragment that crashes SPIM.  Then (or instead) send a bug report to the SPIM developers.